# Merge linux partitions on VPS with CentOS and Plesk

Tags: linux, plesk

On my VPS I am running Plesk 12.5 and CentOS 6.6.

I updated my VPS and I get a 100G extra but somehow, I created a new partition in stead of adding the space to an existing partition. I did this a year ago, and because space wasn't an issue at that time, I left if.

Now space is becoming an issue and I want to use the 100Gig extra. However, I have no clue of how to merge the new partition into the partition Plesk uses.

Below you see a my filesystem:

```
[root@vps dumps]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_plesk-lv_root
                       47G   14G   31G  31% /
tmpfs                 1,9G  8,0K  1,9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1             485M  169M  292M  37% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_plesk-lv_tmp
                      504M   17M  462M   4% /tmp
/dev/vda3              99G  188M   94G   1% /mynewpartition
```

`/dev/vda3` is the new partition that needs to be merged, I think with `/dev/mapper/vg_plesk-lv_root`. I'm not sure about that, because I have not enough experiance on this. But that one is the one that floods every time!

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Not general computing use or administration. Your question may be appropriate on other SE forums such as [Unix/Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @kaylum, thanks, next time I will do that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the details you provided I assume that the name of the volume-group on your server is `vg_plesk`. Also I can see that there is a device `/dev/vda3` which you wish to merge with `vg_plesk-lv_root`.

In order to merge you will have to extent your existing volume-group `vg_plesk`.

First of all unmount `/dev/vda3`

> umount /mynewpartition

Remove or comment the entry for this particular device in `/etc/fstab` and save the file.

Extend existing volume group.

> vgextend vg_plesk /dev/vda3

Extend desired lv `vg_plesk-lv_root`

> lvextend -L+100G /dev/mapper/vg_plesk-lv_root

Resize the extended LV

> resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_plesk-lv_root

Keep in mind all your data in /mynewpartition will be lost when you un-mount the partition `/dev/vda3` so please keep a copy of this data if it is important.

you may also find this [link](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/lv_extend.html) useful.

Hope this helps.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try this. I will make a snapshot of the VPS before doing this so I can always rollback.

Comment: tried it, failed! At the moment I'm restoring the VPS. At reboot, I get this error: http://imgur.com/JWYWI0X.

Comment: Did you remove the entry in fstab which used to mount /dev/vda3 on /mynewpartition?
It seems the system tries to mount it.

Comment: I don't think I did because I have no idea what you are talking about ;)

Comment: ok, there will be a file "/etc/fstab" on your server, open that file and either remove the line which mounts /dev/vda om /mynewpartition or simply comment that line by putting a "#" before that particular line, save the file  and then restart your server.

Comment: commented out that line and retried. Now the reboot was succesvol, VPS is running again. But diskspace is not added, although the `lvextend` command told me that the diskspace was changed from 47G to 147G. But running the `df -h` command still shows me 47Gig. The 100Gig is gone now, no idea where it is...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99701/discussion-between-timo002-and-saurabh).